# How to determine file size from a string in ES?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3

Is there a way to get the size of a file based on a string?

Is it:

```
var size = value.length / 1024;
console.log("File is " + size + " megabytes");
```

I'm posting to a server and sometimes it doesn't go through so I'm guessing there may be a post limit and I'd like to get the file size of the string before trying to post and show a message if the size is too large.

Comment: Assuming `value` is an `<input>` value it is only the name string. You need to get size of file object.. This is a really simple thing to do a search for

Comment: I found some examples for perl. I'll keep looking for JavaScript examples. I do not have a file reference or anything. I only have the string data entered. The user enters code and then I want to tell the user the size the file will be when saved to the HD.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the equivalent of [`Buffer.byteLength`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_bytelength_string_encoding) in ActionScript:

> Returns the actual byte length of a string. This is not the same as [String.prototype.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) since that returns the number of characters in a string.